# Gradle how to change homedir cleaning strategy

Tags: gradle

I use gradle in my microservice project. When I open project in IntelliJ IDEA, I see "often" (a few times per month) missing dependencies even I downloaded them in the past. With tens of microservicies, it is painful to open project, see half of dependencies are missing and need to download them again. I think it is due to cache cleaning as described https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html . If yes, I want to know, if there is possibility to tune parameters, so it does not clean itself so often (yes, one month is very often).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache cleanup can only be disable at the time of writing (Gradle 7.2). For this you need to create the `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties` file with the following content:

```
org.gradle.cache.cleanup=false
```

If not configured explicitly, `$GRADLE_USER_HOME` points to `.gradle` in your user's home directory (`~/.gradle`, `C:\Users\Username`, etc.).

Feature request for fine-granular cache cleanup policy is filed in [Make periodic cache cleanup retention times configurable #7018](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7018).